# cordova application permission to execute bash

Tags: android, bash, cordova

I have plugin code like this:

```
public String exec(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", command });
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
    String output = TextUtils.join("\n", this.read(reader));
    p.waitFor();
    return output;
}
```

and I am trying to run command `"'ls --color=always'"` for now I quote the command. but got exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

how can I execute bash on Android cordova application? Do I need to have root to run bash?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bash is not on the device, it throw permission error when file not found, this code works:

```
public String exec(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process bash = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(bash.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes(command + "\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(bash.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
    bash.waitFor();
    String output = TextUtils.join("\n", this.read(reader));
    return output;
}
```